AudioKit PitchTap in Swift not functioning
I have set up AudioKit 5 in a Swift app and successfully enabled simple pitch detection and pitch generation on a real iPad device. However changes in the code resulted in failure to get output from PitchTap. I stripped the code back to a very basic setup but still could not access PitchTap. I have debugged and determined that the audio engine is correctly configured and running in the right audio session environment. However it seems that for some reason the PitchTap callback is not being executed. I have worked extensively with ChatGPT 4 to attempt to resolve the problem with no success (although it helped a lot with development).
The purpose of the code in its stripped down form is simply to print out detected pitches to console. It does this directly in AppDelegate to minimise issues. Here is the relevant code:
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        // Ensure AudioEngineManager handles audio session configuration and engine start
        AudioEngineManager.shared.configureAudioSession()
        AudioEngineManager.shared.startAudioEngine()
        
        // Print the current audio route
         let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
         print("Current audio route: \(currentRoute)")

        
        //let pitchTracker = PitchTracker.shared
        PitchTracker.shared.startTracking()
        PitchTracker.shared.pitchDetectedHandler = { pitch, amplitude in
            print("Detected pitch: \(pitch), amplitude: \(amplitude)")
            // Here, you can update UI, process the pitch data, etc.
        }
        
        return true
    }
}

import AVFoundation
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit

class AudioEngineManager {
    static let shared = AudioEngineManager()
    var audioEngine = AudioEngine()
    
    func configureAudioSession() {
        do {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .measurement, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            print("Audio session configured.")

        } catch {
            print("Failed to configure audio session: \(error)")
        }
    }


    func startAudioEngine() {
        
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
            print("Audio engine started successfully.")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to start audio engine: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

import Foundation
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit

class PitchTracker {
    static let shared = PitchTracker()

    private let audioEngine: AudioEngine = AudioEngineManager.shared.audioEngine
    var mic: AudioEngine.InputNode?
    
    private var oscillator: Oscillator
    private var pitchTap: PitchTap?
    
    let minimumAmplitudeThreshold: Float = 0.01
    var detectedPitch: Float = 0.0
    var detectedAmplitude: Float = 0.0
    
    var pitchDetectedHandler: ((Float, Float) -> Void)?

    init() {
        oscillator = Oscillator()
        
        setupMicrophone()
        setupPitchTap()
    }
    
    private func setupMicrophone() {
        self.mic = self.audioEngine.input
    }

    private func setupPitchTap() {
        guard let mic = self.mic else {
            print("Microphone is not available.")
            return
        }

        // Initialize PitchTap with microphone input
        self.pitchTap = PitchTap(mic) { [weak self] pitch, amp in
            print("PitchTap callback executed.")

            guard let self = self else {return}
            if amp[0] > self.minimumAmplitudeThreshold {
                self.detectedPitch = pitch[0]
                self.detectedAmplitude = amp[0]
                // Optionally, call pitchDetectedHandler if you're using it to pass data elsewhere
                //self.pitchDetectedHandler?(pitch[0], amp[0])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pitchDetectedHandler?(self.detectedPitch, self.detectedAmplitude)
                }

                // Print detected pitch and amplitude for debugging
                //print("Detected pitch: \(pitch[0]), amplitude: \(amp[0])")
     
            }
        }

    }
    
    func startTracking() {
        self.pitchTap?.start()
        print("Pitch tracking started")
    }

    func stopTracking() {
        self.pitchTap?.stop()
        print("Pitch tracking stopped")
    }

    func startOscillator(frequency: AUValue = 440) {
        // Set the frequency and start the oscillator
        oscillator.frequency = frequency
        oscillator.amplitude = 0.5 // adjust if needed
        oscillator.start()
        print("Oscillator started at frequency: \(frequency)")
    }

    func stopOscillator() {
        oscillator.stop()
        print("Oscillator stopped.")
    }
}


Thanks for your example ! I use SwiftUI, how to remplace this "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" with "struct ContentView: View {" and to accept events ?

To answer my own question, the problem is that AudioEngine needs to have an output attached even if no output is being used. To effect this I added these lines above try audioEngine.start() in AudioEngineManager:
// Set a silence node as the engine's output to ensure it processes audio input
let silence = Fader(audioEngine.input!, gain: 0)
audioEngine.output = silence

Problem solved!
However note that Fader requires import of AudioKitEX.
